# How do I create variables based on an array? PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm quite confused in how would I be able to create variable based on an array's values, my code is:

```
$a = array("red","black","white","green","blue");

for($i=0;$i>5;$i++)
{
$$a[$i] = '0.00';
}

echo $red;
```

I was under the impression that emulating a statement that says `$red = '0.00';` would run properly but alas, it says undefined variable red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
```

you got error in loop, you have used '>' sign, so loop doesn't work, actually... :)

Comment: Oh omg, how did I not see that. That's why the $red isn't getting declared, that explains it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's only your assignation that is wrong.

Use a foreach loop to make it easier, and it will work :

```
$a = array("red","black","white","green","blue");

foreach ($a as $val) {
    $$val = '0.00';
}

echo $red;
```

Output :

`0.00`

Comment: This is also a great answer! this looks more simpler than my for. This just didn't solve my problem, it also taught me a simpler method. I would up this answer although I don't have enough reps, sadly. I'd make sure to up this once I get 15 though.